# Не получается закрыть процессы которых нет в списке List

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, процесс, task

```
private static List<string> name = new List<string>
{
   список процессов которые не нужно убивать.
}
```

По сути я прохожусь по процессам и если процессов которых нету в списке List нужно убить! ( системные процессы входят в список) Убить все процессы кроме системных).

```
static CancellationTokenSource ProcessCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
private static async Task CheckProcess(CancellationToken ct)
{
  while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    await Task.Delay(500, ct);
    Process[] spisok = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process SPDown in spisok)
    {
      if (name.IndexOf(SPDown.ProcessName.ToLower()) < 0)
      {
         SPDown.Kill();
      }
    }
  }
}

public static void Start()
{
   var task = Task.Run(() => CheckProcess(ProcessCTS.Token));
}

public static void Cancel()
{
   ProcessCTS.Cancel();
}
```

Возможно есть недочёты, баги, поправьте меня.

---

Задача заключается в том, что при проверке, нужно пройтись циклом по списку процессов, и исключать те процессы которые нужно убить а именно те которые находятся в списке List. Остальные остановить

Comment: Если вы думаете, что код уже решает задачу (нет известных багов)  и вы просто готовы любой отклик получить о самом коде, то добавьте метку в вопрос [tag:инспекция-кода] (прочтите рекомендации по её использованию в её описании)

Comment: Использование `IndexOf` для сравнения имён сделано специально или от непонимания принципа работы этой функции? И вы уверены, что сможете составить полный список процессов, которые нужно оставить, чтобы не вызывать странные и непонятные глюки в системе?

Comment: @jfs, Код пока ничего не решает, другие процессы не останавливаются.

Comment: Ваш код, очевидно, пытается вести себя **крайне враждебно** и деструктивно по отношению к пользователю. Я бы ни в коем случае не допускал запуска такого кода на моей машине. Если это коммерческий код, я хотел бы узнать название компании, выпускающей такое, чтобы впредь избегать их продуктов.

Comment: @ArteS если код работает не так, как хотелось бы - надо об этом написать в вопросе

Comment: По коду: `ProcessCTS` надо создавать в методе Start, иначе будет невозможно запустить процесс повторно после остановки

Comment: + нет обработки исключений. Достаточно одного процесса, который слишком быстро завершится, чтобы убивалка процессов остановилась

Comment: Обработка исключений будет. @VladD, для себя пишу ( не компания).

Comment: @ArteS: Если пишете для себя, подумайте, что произойдёт, если во время запуска этого кода будет, к примеру, записываться CD.

Comment: @VladD, Я уже подумал обо всём) Какое CD?)) Данный код будет запускаться, только в случае если система заблокирована  например тем же винлокером, я прохожу список процессов, убиваю винлокер или тому-подобие программ зловредов, а дальнейшие действия за пользователем.

Comment: @ArteS: Ну, хороший винлокер назовёт свой процесс explorer.exe, наши действия? То есть если это аварийная спасательная тулза, то конечно да, тут уж плевать на всё остальное.

Comment: @VladD, Да такое тоже возможно, но это уже другая проблема) Ну даже если и назовёт ( его фактически можно убить и восстановить)

Comment: @ArteS: Это я к тому, что вы по имени файла вряд ли сможете определить, хороший файл или нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58083/discussion-between-artes-and-vladd).